# Using JSweet to Transpile Java->JS, 'matches' error

Tags: javascript, java, match, transpiler, jsweet

I'm new to JS. I've written two large Java classes that I want to turn into JS using JSweet. The first smaller one transpiled without issue. With the second, I've hit a wall. It throws this error twice, and no others:

```
Line 55: property 'matches' does not exist on type 'string'. Did you mean 'match'?
```

Line 55 in my class is as follows:

```
private String name;
```

name is at the class level, and given a value later by an object constructor, by which I mean it is contained within no other brackets besides the class. (It happens to be line 55 due to some previous skeleton classes I added before the class I'm transpiling to define dependancies)

My one theory was that the following line was causing the issues:

```
if(pointer.content.equals(sub_table.get_name()))
```

So I changed it to this:

```
if(pointer.content.compareTo(sub_table.get_name())==0)
```

The idea being that these are two different ways to compare strings, and matches vs. match in JS are also different ways to compare data, and that perhaps I was trying to transpile a method that JS doesn't like. However, the error has not changed. Any clues?

Comment: is your code trying to access the `matches` property on the `name` variable?

Comment: It does twice, but has nothing to do with name. I'll try editing that. If that is the answer, my confusion is why the error is being pointed to line 55.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was line 350:

```
if((words[i - 2].matches("\\d*") && words[i-1].equals("+")) && words[i].matches("\\d*"))
```

I changed it to:

```
if((isNumeric(words[i - 2]) && words[i-1].equals("+")) && isNumeric(words[i]))
```

and I added isNumeric as a method:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    if (strNum == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Still don't understand why the error was showing on line 55. Matches works as intended in java, so js or jsweet just doesn't like it used like that.